# Modules installed globally not found in VS Code Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pip, jupyter-notebook

I've installed several Python modules from PyPi globally on Mac OS using `pip3`. Running `pip3 list` confirms that they are installed:

```
user@users-MacBook-Pro SER-neural-net % pip3 list
Package            Version
------------------ ---------
appdirs            1.4.4
audioread          3.0.0
...
librosa            0.9.2
numpy              1.23.4
pip                22.3.1
scikit-learn       1.1.3
scipy              1.9.3
sklearn            0.0.post1
sounddevice        0.4.5
soundfile          0.11.0
torch              1.13.0
...
```

From the integrated terminal in VS Code where I am running the notebook, I have run the following commands to determine which Python interpreter to use:

```
user@users-MacBook-Pro SER-neural-net % which pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
user@users-MacBook-Pro SER-neural-net % which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
user@users-MacBook-Pro SER-neural-net % python3 --version
Python 3.7.9
```

I have selected the appropriate interpreter at the top right of Jupyter Notebook view in VS Code:
[image: currently selected interpreter]

But the modules confirmed to be installed for this interpreter are not found:
[image]

What has gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:
python3 -m pip install --user (library)

for example:
python3 -m pip install --user pandas

Comment: This did the trick, thank you and nice work answering your first question!  Can you explain why the modules needed to be installed this way?

Comment: Becausee it enables the installation and management of third party software packages with features and functionality not found in the Python standard library.